# Javascript - can this be rewritten in a loop?

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code but I am want to know if there is a simpler way of doing it?

```
cols = new Array("white","blue","green","pink");

pg = new Array();
pg[0] = new Object();
pg[0].opt = new Array();
pg[0].opt[0] = new Object();

// Instead of doing individually
/* 
pg[0].opt[0].white = new Array();
pg[0].opt[0].blue  = new Array();
pg[0].opt[0].green = new Array();
pg[0].opt[0].pink  = new Array();
*/
// Can I write a for loop through the colours;
/* 
for(n=0; n<=3; n++){
   pg[0].opt[0].cols[n] = new Array();
};
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a `for...next` loop

Comment: Why is this tagged with `jquery`? jQuery is not related with the problem/question.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use the constructors of `Array` and `Object`? Why not simply `[ ]` and `{ }`? `pg = [ { opt: [ { } ] } ]`

Comment: PLEASE: `for(let i=0; i<cols.length; i++){`

Comment: Other than the fact all of the code above relies on [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) -- declare your variables! :-) -- your version at the end is very close, you've just used `cols` slightly incorrectly. It would be just `pg[[0].opt[0][cols[n]] = new Array();` (but don't use `new Array()` or `new Object()`, use `[]` and `{}`). Also note that you can start with `pg = [{opt: [{}]}]` rather than those four initial assignments.

Comment: Thanks but I have read the comments and still don't really get it.